# Return 0 for negative numbers using a short list of functions

Tags: functions

I'm using a CAD software that allows you to calculate a value using a small set of built in functions. I have the formula complete for the input (call it 'x') of this formula, I just need to return either 0 if 'x' is negative or 'x' if not.

Here's the list of formulas/functions available:

- ABS (absolute)
- ACOS (Arccosine)
- ASIN (Arcsine)
- ATAN (Arctan)
- COS (Cosine)
- COSH (Hyperbolic Cosine)
- INT (Truncate to Integer)
- LOG (Log base e)
- LOG10 (Log base 10)
- SIN (Sine)
- SINH (Hyperbolic Sine)
- SQR (Square root)
- TAN (Tangent)
- TANH (Hyperbolic Tangent)

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What does your software do if you try to take the square root of a negative number? If it generates an error you can catch then you can construct your answer pretty easily.

Comment: @Arthur That's why I started my comment with a question. In any case the accepted answer to the duplicate question is the way to go.

Comment: @EthanBolker its not a coded thing, just a UI to create formula (I'll add a screenshot to my post)

Comment: @EthanBolker You're right. I didn't see "you can catch" in your comment.

Comment: @MartinR yeah, its a duplicate, sorry... its frustrating when you search but nothing comes up for what you're trying to find... ended up using (Abs(x) + x)/2. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is $$\frac{x+|x|}{2}$$ which, for positive values of $x$, is $$\frac{x+x}{2}=x,$$
and for negative values of $x$ is $$\frac{x-x}{2}=0$$

Comment: Yep, this is what I needed, thanks! (I have to wait a few minutes before I can mark it as the answer, but I will once I can)

Answer (score 1):

The absolute value can be seen as a "decision function", as its behavior ($+x$ or $-x$) depends on the comparison $x\ge0$.

It can be used for a sign function,

$$\text{sgn}(x)=\frac{|x|}{x}$$ (provided $x\ne0$).

From this you deriv a "positive" function ($1$ for positive, $0$ otherwise),

$$\text{pos}(x)=\frac{\text{sgn}(x)+1}2.$$

Then

$$x\text{ pos}(x)=\frac{|x|+x}2$$ has the desired behavior (even for $x=0$).

---

If the range of $x$ is bounded ($|x|<X$), you can also exploit the floor function (INT), via

$$\text{pos}(x)=\left\lfloor\frac xX\right\rfloor+1.$$

---

In case these functions would be missing, the absolute value is also

$$\sqrt{x^2},$$ and the floor can even be emulated from $$\arctan(\tan(x))$$

but this is very inefficient and not completely accurate.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*:

Since
$$|x|=\begin{cases}x\text{ if }x\ge 0\\-x\text{ if }x<0\end{cases}$$
Then
$$x+|x|=\begin{cases}x+x\text{ if }x\ge 0\\x-x\text{ if }x<0\end{cases}$$